# Add signature to stored procedure using PowerShell SMO

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I want to add a signature to a stored procedure using PowerShell SMO. The equivalent command in TSQL is:

```
ADD SIGNATURE TO [myprocedure] BY CERTIFICATE [mycertificate] with password = 'CertificatePW'
```

How do I do this using PowerShell SMO without having to resort to using any form of TSQL?

Comment: The SMO object model currently does not provide this capability. Consider submitting a suggestion on [Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). I use PowerShell helper functions to address gaps in SMO for my certificate management tasks (SMO executes T-SQL for most functionality anyway). Let me know if those might be helpful to you and I'll share code snippets as an answer.